# What are some common church fathers cited for patristic dispensational premillennialism?

Tags: church-fathers, premillennialism, dispensationalism

What are some common church fathers cited as believers in dispensational premillennialism?

Comment: Are you aware that there are _any_ church fathers of the Patristic Era (1st to 8th centuries) who held to that teaching ?

Comment: My understanding is that the theory was invented by Dispensational Brethrenism (J N D and W K in particular) in the mid 1800s and was a driving force behind the effort of the USA and UK to fund and negotiate the situation in  1948 which we still see unfolding before us in 2023. Up-voted +1.

Comment: @NigelJ yes, that is my theory of history as well, but I am curious to see if there are any that are commonly cited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dispensations** There are many theological histories that show that the idea that human (redemptive) history was divided into several *dispensations* by various old theologians. The simplest being "the Age of the Father, the Age of the Son, and the Age of the Spirit." The Jewish rabbis also divided history into Ages of different sorts. (The former Age, and the Later Age, and the Age to come.)

**Premillennialism** And there is much debate as to how many, if any, "apostolic fathers" referred to a millennium with an Advent of Christ to inaugurate it. Several of the ancient writers seem to have advocated such an event and period of time. And as Eusebius showed, there was even debate back in the first few Christian centuries over this interpretation of scripture.

**Modern Dispensationalism** However when *dispensationalism* is used as an adjective to describe premillennialism, this introduces an altogether different theory of eschatology...and a different presentation of Dispensations. Some historians have used the terminology "New Premillennialism", when referring to modern Dispensationalism, to distinguish it from "Old Premillennialism." [See Hummel, *The Rise and Fall of Dispensationalism*, 2023]

As the comments above reveal, Dispensational Premillennialism is a nineteenth century phenomenon. It began to teach a dispensational time with successive failures, separation of Jew and Gentile, immanent rapture of the Church, a Jewish dominated millennium, and a pessimistic view of the effectiveness of the Church to the End. But these dogmas were not taught by nor accepted by orthodox Christian churches.

Most of these new doctrines are recognized as modern inventions, speculative and imaginative. Occasionally one will find a modern defender of
Dispensationalism who will allege that there is an obscure passage in the Ancient Father's writing that mentioned one of the particular interpretations. Usually the passage is tweaked or taken out of context to fit the modern take on it. But other apologists for Disp. will asseverate that these doctrines were unknown, and never mentioned in any commentary in history, until *revealed* to John N. Darby in the 1800s! [H.A. Ironside, "The Mysteries of God",1946, p. 50-51]

It can be safely said that **Dispensational Premillennialism**, as a dogma of eschatology, was never taught by the Apostolic Fathers---even though one or two misguided souls may try to *cherry pick* out a phrase here or there to support it. Church Fathers are often cite for the doctrine of Premillennialism...Church Fathers are cited for the doctrine of Dispensations...but none, legitimately, for the modern Dispensational eschatology (and ecclesiology).